# Sql column with multiple time formats

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have Big data incoming from csv file. this file has a column  for date which has two types of date format in it - Unixtimestamp and normal Timestamp. Now i want to manage this column efficiently. We should probably be converting all the dates to a common format, but i do not know how to acheive it. You can suggest an SQL query to me or pyspark dataframe approach also works.

Answer (score 0):

In a Big Data architeture, you must think  that the incoming data must be refined before consumed, so you need to create a intermediary table to treat the data. In this intermediary table you can convert both data types in a unique data type anda then use this refined table consume the data.

Answer (score 0):

By using a data frame, you can add a new column and apply conditions to transform your UNIX timestamp to a regular timestamp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).